# How to fix java.lang.SecurityException Android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-securityexception

Actually i've developed an app for wide range of devices and that app is also used by [Orderman](https://www.orderman.com/it/palmari/orderman5/), that's a device that uses radio frequencies instead of Wi-Fi and only in Orderman devices the app crash sometimes when the device is locked and i can't even get what exactly cause the crash.

The log is got from firebase crashlytics as i can't even emulate the crash with the device connected to PC it's like crash sometimes and sometimes don't.

Orderman devices have all Android 4.2.2

Here is full log from firebase:

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException
Neither user 10034 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1425)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1379)
android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.acquireWakeLock (IPowerManager.java:299)
android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquireLocked (PowerManager.java:770)
android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire (PowerManager.java:755)
android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService (WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:108)
com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver.doStartService (Origine sconosciuta:8)
com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzbm.onReceive (Origine sconosciuta:38)
com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver.onReceive (Origine sconosciuta:6)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2376)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:141)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1310)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5041)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:795)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:562)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing permission wake-lock

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: i'm gonna try it, but actually other devices with other Android versions doesn't have that problem..